# Android Dialog Shadow

Tags: java, android, dialog, shadow

I work with android and I used [android-styled-dialogs](https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs) project for custom dialogs

I have custom theme

```
 <style name="DialogStyleDark.Custom">
        <item name="dialogBackground">@color/tt_gray_2</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@color/tt_light_blue</item>
        <item name="titleSeparatorColor">@color/sdl_button_separator_dark</item>
        <item name="messageTextColor">@color/sdl_message_text_dark</item>
        <item name="buttonTextColor">@color/sdl_button_text_dark</item>
        <item name="buttonSeparatorColor">@color/sdl_button_separator_dark</item>
        <item name="buttonBackgroundColorNormal">@color/sdl_button_normal_dark</item>
        <item name="buttonBackgroundColorPressed">@color/tt_gray_1</item>
        <item name="buttonBackgroundColorFocused">@color/tt_gray_1</item>
    </style>
```

dialog seems like this

[image]

I want to it has shadow as android native dialogs

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Since I did much research in how to customize and recolor the default holo dialogs I can tell you that this is done with drawables. So just create some nice png files with shadows and use them as background.

[Here you can find the orginal xml file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog_holo.xml) which is used by alert holo themed dialogs.